# Отключить включение функции активного курсора по клавише F7 в Firefox?

Tags: firefox

Как отключить включение/отключение функции активного курсора по клавише <kbd>F7</kbd> в Firefox? У меня используется ввод с помощью функциональных клавиш, нужна <kbd>F7</kbd>, но браузер забил на неё свою функцию активного курсора, как-то можно эту функцию отключить совсем или переназначить на другую кнопку хотя бы?

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я вижу, вы можете отключить это на странице
`about:config`, выставив параметр
`accessibility.browsewithcaret_shortcut.enabled`
в `false`.